# How to use the name() method in Java enums

Tags: java

I am going through some code uses the `name` method of a  Java Enum.

Can anyone please explain to me how and where to use the `name()` method of Enum in java.

Comment: You use it just like any other method wherever you need the name of the Enum value.  What is your doubt?

Comment: Enum.name() returns a String that contains the exact name that this Enum 'instance' has. Its useful for key-value storage, for example the database 'Neo4j' uses it extensively to refer to properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
enum Direction {
  NORTH("north"), SOUTH("south"), EAST("east"), WEST("west");

  private final String printableValue;

  Direction(String printableValue) {
    this.printableValue = printableValue;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return printableValue;
  }
}
```

then this code:

```
Direction travelDirection = Direction.NORTH;
System.out.println("I am going " + travelDirection);
```

will print

```
I am going north
```

but this code:

```
Direction travelDirection = Direction.NORTH;
System.out.println("I am going " + travelDirection.name());
```

will print

```
I am going NORTH
```

Answer (score 3):

The `name()` method is pretty much like `toString()` except that it is declared final, so the enum definition cannot change it. This might be important e.g. when writing a framework to serialize data, where you have to rely on the fact that the name of an enum is a single Java identifier which uniquely identifies the constant. There might be some more applications, but as the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) says:

> Most programmers should use the `toString()` method in preference to
>   this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name.

In general I'd say you should use `toString()` when the output is intended for a human reader, and `name()` when it is aimed at another process for parsing in some way.